# T-SQL: convert columns to rows and insert/update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Looking for non fancy, easily debugable for junior developer solution...
In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have to update data from `#data` table to `#tests` table in desired format. I am not sure how I would archive result using T-SQL query?

**NOTE**: temp tables have only 3 columns for sample purpose only but real table have more than 50 columns for each set.

Here is what my tables look like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tests') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #tests
GO

CREATE TABLE #tests
(
    id int,
    FirstName varchar(100),
    LastName varchar(100),
    UniueNumber varchar(100)
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #data
GO

CREATE TABLE #data
(
    id int,
    FirstName1 varchar(100),
    LastName1 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber1 varchar(100),
    FirstName2 varchar(100),
    LastName2 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber2 varchar(100),
    FirstName3 varchar(100),
    LastName3 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber3 varchar(100),
    FirstName4 varchar(100),
    LastName4 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber4 varchar(100),
    FirstName5 varchar(100),
    LastName5 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber5 varchar(100),
    FirstName6 varchar(100),
    LastName6 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber6 varchar(100),
    FirstName7 varchar(100),
    LastName7 varchar(100),
    UniueNumber7 varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #data 
VALUES (111, 'Tom', 'M', '12345', 'Sam', 'M', '65432', 'Chris', 'PATT', '54656', 'Sean', 'Meyer', '865554', 'Mike', 'Max', '999999', 'Tee', 'itc', '656546444', 'Mickey', 'Mul', '65443231')

INSERT INTO #data  
VALUES (222, 'Kurr', 'P', '22222', 'Yammy', 'G', '33333', 'Saras', 'pi', '55555', 'Man', 'Shey', '666666', 'Max', 'Dopit', '66666678', '', '', '', '', '', '')

INSERT INTO #data 
VALUES (333, 'Mia', 'K', '625344', 'Tee', 'TE', '777766', 'david', 'mot', '4444444', 'Jeff', 'August', '5666666', 'Mylee', 'Max', '0000000', '', '', '', 'Amy', 'Marr', '55543444')

SELECT * 
FROM #data
```

I want to insert/update data into #tests table from #data table.
Insert data into #tests table if id and UniqueNumber combination does not exists from #data table. If combination exists then update data into #tests table from #data table

This is desired output into #tests table

[image]

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Yes @marc_s, I agree with you but hope my company see same too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without using Dynamic SQL

**To be clear:** UNPIVOT would be more performant, but you don't have to enumerate the 50 columns.

This is assuming your columns end with a NUMERIC  i.e. `FirstName##`

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,UniueNumber  -- You could use SSN = UniueNumber  
 From  (
        SELECT A.ID
              ,Grp
              ,Col = replace([Key],Grp,'')
              ,Value
        FROM #data A
        Cross Apply (
                        Select [Key]
                              ,Value
                              ,Grp = substring([Key],patindex('%[0-9]%',[Key]),25)
                         From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  ) ) 
                    ) B
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Col in ([FirstName],[LastName],[UniueNumber]) ) pvt
 Order By ID,Grp
```

**Results**

[image]

**UPDATE XML Version**

```
Select ID
      ,FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,UniueNumber
 From  (
        SELECT A.ID
              ,Grp  = substring(Item,patindex('%[0-9]%',Item),50)
              ,Col  = replace(Item,substring(Item,patindex('%[0-9]%',Item),50),'')
              ,Value
        FROM #data A
        Cross Apply ( values (convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML RAW)))) B(XData)
        Cross Apply (
                        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                         From  B.XData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                    ) C
        Where Item not in ('ID')
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Col in (FirstName,LastName,UniueNumber) ) pvt
 Order By ID,Grp
```

Comment: Hello @John Cappelletti, I have database in SQL 2008 R2 and JSON path works SQL 2016 and later...

Comment: @Sanjay Woof!  Time to upgrade.  There is a similar approach use XML rather than JSON.  Give me a moment to update/

Comment: @Sanjay See Update XML Version

Comment: It is making Unique Numbers null too.

Comment: @Sanjay With the provided Sample I see no NULL values.  There are a few empty string in  ID 222 and 333

Comment: @Sanjay Here is a working example of the XML version.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=aa552ed6f1d8334b36d868c4a7c92a3d

Answer (score 1):

One way is to query each group of columns separately and `UNION` the results

```
SELECT 
    id int,
    FirstName1 as FirstName,
    LastName1 as LastName,
    UniueNumber1 AS SSN
FROM #data
UNION 
SELECT 
    id int,
    FirstName2 as FirstName,
    LastName2 as LastName,
    UniueNumber2 AS SSN
FROM #data
UNION 
...
```

There's not a way to cleanly "loop through" the 7 groups of columns - you'll spend more time building a loop to create the query dynamically than just copying and pasting the query 6 times and changing the number.

Of course, it's best to avoid the type of structure you have in `#data` now if at all possible.

Comment: My real table have more than 50 columns for each set. For sample data only, I gave 3 columns in question.

Comment: Well, like I said there's not a clean way to convert column groups like that to rows  -so you need to decide if you want to copy.paste and change the number (e.g. using a find/replace) or come up with some loop to create the SQL dynamically. The latter wouldn't be _too_ bad in some other language (javascript/python/etc.) but there's not an easy way to do that in SQL.

Comment: I understand and I can write code in multiple upset statement for each set but that I don't like idea of repeating same code for multiple columns

Comment: Well I don't like the idea of dynamic SQL or some bizarre XML/JSON pivoting that is incredible hard (for me) to understand exactly what's happening so I can diagnose it. But to each his own...